# NVIDIA-SMI couldn't find libnvidia-ml.so library

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I have the following Nvidia graphics card in my laptop

```
ant@Anthill ~> lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
    Kernel driver in use: i915
--
07:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208M [GeForce GT 740M] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Lenovo GK208M [GeForce GT 740M]
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
```

I have installed drivers the following way

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get install nvidia-370 nvidia-prime
```

And cuda toolkit by downloading cuda-7.5 binary from nvidia official site

```
sudo ./NVidia-cuda-7.5.run
```

All these installations were done after shifting to **tty** and stopping XOrg

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

Now after restarting

```
ant@Anthill ~> nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI couldn't find libnvidia-ml.so library in your system. Please make sure that the NVIDIA Display Driver is properly installed and present in your system.
Please also try adding directory that contains libnvidia-ml.so to your system PATH.
```

**libnvidia-ml.so** is present here

```
ant@Anthill ~> ls /usr/lib/nvidia-370
alt_ld.so.conf                 libGLX_indirect.so.0@            libnvidia-fatbinaryloader.so.370.28
bin/                           libGLX_nvidia.so.0@              libnvidia-fbc.so.370.28
ld.so.conf                     libGLX_nvidia.so.370.28          libnvidia-glcore.so.370.28
libEGL_nvidia.so.0@            libGLX.so@                       libnvidia-glsi.so.370.28
libEGL_nvidia.so.370.28        libGLX.so.0                      libnvidia-ifr.so@
libEGL.so@                     libnvcuvid.so@                   libnvidia-ifr.so.1@
libEGL.so.1                    libnvcuvid.so.1@                 libnvidia-ifr.so.370.28
libGLdispatch.so.0             libnvcuvid.so.370.28             libnvidia-ml.so@
libGLESv1_CM_nvidia.so.1@      libnvidia-cfg.so@                libnvidia-ml.so.1@
libGLESv1_CM_nvidia.so.370.28  libnvidia-cfg.so.1@              libnvidia-ml.so.370.28
libGLESv1_CM.so@               libnvidia-cfg.so.370.28          libnvidia-ptxjitcompiler.so.370.28
libGLESv1_CM.so.1              libnvidia-compiler.so@           libnvidia-tls.so.370.28
libGLESv2_nvidia.so.2@         libnvidia-compiler.so.1@         libnvidia-wfb.so.370.28
libGLESv2_nvidia.so.370.28     libnvidia-compiler.so.370.28     libOpenGL.so@
libGLESv2.so@                  libnvidia-eglcore.so.370.28      libOpenGL.so.0
libGLESv2.so.2                 libnvidia-egl-wayland.so.370.28  tls/
libGL.so@                      libnvidia-encode.so@             vdpau/
libGL.so.1@                    libnvidia-encode.so.1@           xorg/
libGL.so.1.0.0                 libnvidia-encode.so.370.28
```

I tried adding this dir to the PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH also. Both did not work.

Also,

```
ls /dev | grep nvidia
```

Yields nothing. That is no devices are present with `/dev/nivida*`

Any suggestion to get this working?
Where does `nvidia-smi` try to find the `libnvidia-ml.so`?

Comment: Not really sure, but I think you should check with the command `prime-select`. This command will alter the lookup paths for the graphics library for Intel and Nvidia.

Answer (score 8):

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/nvidia-367/libnvidia-ml.so nvidia-smi
```

Comment: I tried to use LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/nvidia-375/libnvidia-ml.so nvidia-smi
but got 
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.

Answer (score 4):

my error was solved by doing this way

This led me to finding another solution by looking into **/etc/nvidia-container-runtime/config.toml** file where the ldconfig is by default set to **"@/sbin/ldconfig"**. This for some reason seems to not be working and also produces the error above:

```
root@banshee:/var/log# docker run --rm --gpus=all nvidia/cuda:11.4-base nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI couldn't find libnvidia-ml.so library in your system. Please make sure that the NVIDIA Display Driver is properly installed and present in your system.
Please also try adding directory that contains libnvidia-ml.so to your system PATH.
```

Changing the ldconfig path to "/sbin/ldconfig" (instead of "@/sbin/ldconfig") does indeed fix the problem:

```
root@banshee:/var/log# docker run --rm --gpus=all nvidia/cuda:11.4-base nvidia-smi
Sun Jan  5 20:39:45 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 430.64       Driver Version: 430.64       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 970     On   | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 32%   39C    P8    16W / 170W |    422MiB /  4038MiB |      3%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

source : [github](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/issues/1163)

Comment: This worked for me, too. (Debian 11, Nvidia 390.147 drivers and Cuda 11.6)

Comment: +1 on Debian 11, NVIDIA-SMI 460.91.03, Driver Version: 460.91.03, CUDA Version: 11.2

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this problem after some nvidia-docker containers crashed. `libnvidia-ml.so` presented at `/usr/lib/nvidia-<version>`, but `nvidia-smi` kept complaining.

I fixed the problem by `sudo ldconfig.real`

Comment: This didn't work for me - what is `sudo ldconfig.real` supposed to do?

Comment: @smörkex I suppose `ldconfig.real` re-configured some paths so `nvidia-smi` can discover `libnvidia-ml.so`. But my answer was from 2018, a lot may have changed over the years.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem.
I realized it was because the nvidia drivers where not loaded during boot, as I was using bumblebee. I found out it ran ok when using `optirun`.
First make sure that you are using Nvidia drivers not Nouveau, and that you have removed and blacklisted Nouveau drivers
If you have Nvidia drivers already installed switch graphics card by launching **NVIDIA X Server Settings** and select your Nvidia GPU at PRIME Profiles tab. You might have to restart your session after doing that.
Run

```
cat /proc/acpi/bbswitch
```

to make sure that your gpu is switched on if your are using bbswitch, you should get something like:

```
0000:02:00.0 ON
```

I think it should run now.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem after a driver upgrade.

I fixed it changing the LDCONFIG file:

```
sudo vi /etc/ld.so.conf.d/cuda-8-0.conf
```

With the content

```
/usr/local/cuda-8.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib 
/usr/lib/nvidia-<PUT_YOUR_VERSION_HERE>
```