# apt-get operations fail, because of invalid ld.so lookup

Tags: apt, nvidia, sudo, cuda

All of my apt-get operations are failing, because somewhere there seems to be a file calling **ld.so** with a file that no longer exist. This means I can no longer use apt-get to install or update my dependencies!

I'm running Lubuntu 16.04.

I believe this started to occur because of an auto-update that occurred with Nvidia CUDA. Starting last week, I started seeing this line show up in my terminal after running commands that have nothing to do with CUDA.

```
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/nvidia-375/libnvidia-ml.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
```

I went to look into this and found that the file **/usr/lib/nvidia-375/libnvidia-ml.so** did not exist on my system, that instead there was a **libnvidia-ml.so** file in a folder that seemed to be for an update of the same package, **/usr/lib/nvidia-382**.

I thought that with a reboot and some updates this problem would go away, but today I realize that I can no longer do most **apt-get** commands. For example, when I run an install command, I get a huge log output, that includes the above line hundreds of times, and the installation ultimately fails.

I've copy-and-pasted one of those outputs into a gist (it was too big to put inside this post). This was the result from output from trying to run `sudo apt-get install vlc` (but it fails similarly with any install). https://gist.github.com/travellingprog/00a08cff1019f7a12d36b975dff62c92

I don't even use CUDA these days, so this is especially annoying. One of the things I tried was to uninstall nvidia-382. The uninstallation itself seems to have worked, and it seems to have removed CUDA 9 along with it, but the problem still persists.

The thing is I have no idea what package or file keeps asking for this non-existing file in /usr/lib/nvidia-375.

Can someone please help?

**Update 2017-11-01**

I seem to get this error **anytime I run a `sudo` command**.

I tried running `ldd /usr/bin/sudo` and `ldd /usr/bin/apt-get` and neither of them list this Nvidia file. I looked in the folder */etc/ld.so.conf.d* and found a file called *cuda-9-0.conf*, despite the fact that CUDA should be removed. So I renamed it to *cuda-9-0.backup* and ran `sudo ldconfig`.

This didn't fix it, I still get the error message on every `sudo` command.

I also decided to check the cache, and I'm not sure if this is pointing to the issue:

```
# sudo ldconfig -p | grep nvidia
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/nvidia-375/libnvidia-ml.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
libnvidia-gtk3.so.384.81 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libnvidia-gtk3.so.384.81
libnvidia-gtk2.so.384.81 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libnvidia-gtk2.so.384.81
```

Comment: Try the options from: https://askubuntu.com/questions/833862/nvidia-smi-couldnt-find-libnvidia-ml-so-library

Comment: Are you purging when you remove stuff you don't need anymore? `sudo apt purge $PACKAGE_NAME`? Sometimes it helps if files aren't properly removed to install the package again first (eg `sudo apt-get install --reinstall $PACKAGE_NAME`) and then to purge the package. I often then use `locate -i $BINARY_NAME` to find anything left over that needs manually deleting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @muru's [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/973412/754005) and @pbhj's [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/971028/apt-get-operations-fail-because-of-invalid-ld-so-lookup#comment1561061_973412) to that answer, I found that the issue was that the environment variable `LD_PRELOAD` was being set to "/usr/lib/nvidia-375/libnvidia-ml.so" in the file `/etc/environment`.

I most likely added the line in that file myself a long time ago, when I first set up CUDA. I'm guessing this was a hack to an issue I was having at that time, that required setting LD_PRELOAD at the `sudo` level.

As @muru demonstrated, it is pretty easy to reproduce the error message by setting the LD_PRELOAD environment variable to a file that does not exist. Still, my shell initialization files did not set it, and `env | grep LD_PRELOAD` returned nothing.

However, (thanks to @pbhj's comment), I found out that while running `sudo apt-get update` would display the error a ton of times in the output, `sudo env -u LD_PRELOAD apt-get update` only displayed it once, at the very top of the output. Then I found that `sudo env | grep LD_PRELOAD` showed that it was indeed set to the non-existing file, for `sudo` commands.

Aside from `/etc/environment`, anyone having this issue should also look at the file `/etc/sudoers` (which you should edit with `sudo visudo`) and any files in the folder `/etc/sudoers.d/`.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have set the `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable somewhere:

```
$ /bin/true
$ export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/nvidia-375/libnvidia-ml.so
$ /bin/true
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/nvidia-375/libnvidia-ml.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
```

I'd suggest that you check your shell initialization files (`~/.{bashrc,profile}`, `/etc/{bash.bashrc,profile,profile.d/*}`). Or run this command:

```
PS4=' ${BASH_SOURCE}:${LINENO} ' bash -lixc exit |& grep LD_PRELOAD
```

Comment: why do you do `/bin/true` either side of the export?

Comment: @pbhj because `/bin/true` is a command that otherwise has minimal dependencies and is guaranteed to succeed. And, of course, in the first try it had no problems, but after the export, I got the same error as OP.

Comment: Ah, apologies, skimmed over that too fast, I thought you were suggesting a fix there! Yes, testing to show the potential origin of the error. `env | grep LD_PRELOAD` would show it too, also `env -i $COMMAND` should work with a clean environment and so not have the preload (`env -u LD_PRELOAD $COMMAND` might be better).

Comment: I wish I could give the bounty to both you and @pbhj . My user shell initialization files had nothing, and `env | grep LD_PRELOAD` returned nothing either, but then I found that `sudo env | grep LD_PRELOAD` did show the environment variable LD_PRELOAD as set to the non-existing `libnvidia-ml.so`. After digging to figure out where root-only environment variables could be set, found LD_PRELOAD being set in `/etc/environment`. Thank you so much to both of you for steering me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with:

`dpkg-reconfigure nvidia-***`

This may solve your issue reconfiguring and re-installing if needed!