# NVIDIA-SMI couldn't find libnvidia-ml.so library and nothing in /usr/lib/nvidia

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I got the error below when I ran `nvidia-smi`:

```
$ nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI couldn't find libnvidia-ml.so library in your system. Please make sure that the NVIDIA Display Driver is properly installed and present in your system.
Please also try adding directory that contains libnvidia-ml.so to your system PATH.
```

I looked for where `libnvidia-ml.so` could be:

```
$ locate libnvidia-ml.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnvidia-ml.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-ml.so
```

It can detect the graphics card:

```
$ lspci -vnn | grep VGA -A 12
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GP104 [GeForce GTX 1070 Ti] [10de:1b82] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: eVga.com. Corp. GP104 [GeForce GTX 1070 Ti] [3842:5671]
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 59
        Memory at fa000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
        Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
        I/O ports at e000 [size=128]
        [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: nvidia
        Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

And trying to find the nvidia-driver files, there is not the driver that I installed (440) but one that I can't find any other reference to except here (384)
**Should I delete that folder?**:

```
$ ls /usr/lib/nvidia*
/usr/lib/nvidia/
/usr/lib/nvidia-384/
```

System Info:

```
$ uname -m && cat /etc/*release
x86_64
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS"

$ uname -r
4.15.0-65-generic
```

I definitely didn't properly purge previous nvidia drivers before installing the new one, and now I've tried the following procedure so many times with different variations and can't get it to work:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
$ sudo apt update
$ ubuntu-drivers devices
$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-440 # the recommended one by ubuntu-drivers
$ sudo reboot
```

Comment: How did you install the drivers? My Mint 19.2 system has the same thing in **/usr/lib/nvidia** (using the 440.36 drivers), so that's not the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NVIDIA-SMI couldn't find libnvidia-ml.so library](https://askubuntu.com/questions/833862/nvidia-smi-couldnt-find-libnvidia-ml-so-library)?

Comment: Try running `LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/nvidia-XXX/libnvidia-ml.so nvidia-smi` and change the `XXX` by the driver version you have (exp: 440)

Comment: i have no such `/usr/lib/nvidia-440/` folder @singrium

Comment: NOT a duplicate of that question because in that case, user was just missing path to libnvidia-ml.so in the driver folder, whereas everytime I download the driver, it does not include any file and in my comment above, does not even make a folder in /usr/lib/

Comment: We've had the same problem, I'm just not sure it was due to the exact same files, what we did was both these exports and installing `libcudnn` and `cudnn`: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda/lib64"
; export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda`

Comment: You probably still haven't fully purged the old nvidia drivers and config files;  Try sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  , then see if any are left (some do not start with "nvidia") - dpkg -l |grep nvidia  Then reinstall

Comment: If there are some left, I can safely remove all such files?

Comment: If your lspci shows the nouveau driver in use, then it should be OK to get rid of old nvidia files. You seemed to be running the nvidia driver, was anything other than nvidia-smi having problems? Follow the links /usr/lib/libnvidia-ml.so ... and see which driver (in the final name) is actually in use -- should have a 440 in the name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved by following suggestions from [ubfan1](https://askubuntu.com/users/82196/ubfan1) and other suggestions from various sources. Specifically:

BTW this is all in console mode (for me, alt+ctrl+F2)

Enter login + password as usual

Removing ALL nvidia software:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

Checking what's left:

```
dpkg -l | grep nvidia
```

Then I deleted the ones that showed up (mostly libnvidia-* but also xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-xxx`)

```
sudo apt-get purge libnvidia* xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-440 
sudo apt autoremove
```

Now reinstall everything including nvidia-common

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-common
```

Find the right driver again

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
ubuntu-drivers devices
sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-440 # the recommended one by ubuntu-drivers
update-initramfs -u # needed to do this so rebooting wouldn't lose configuration I think
sudo reboot
```